# String to list of characters

Tags: haskell

I was wondering if I can convert a string to a list of characters?

```
"jt5x=!" -> ["j","t","5","x","=","!"]
```

Essentially, it would be?

```
example :: String -> [Char]
```

Comment: `example = id`.

Comment: `type String = [Char]`. A `String` is just a list of `Char`…

Comment: @user3237465 That should be an answer!

Comment: yes guys this is a basic question and yes the answer is trivial but why downvote? There is nothing wrong with the question (indeed many beginners might find the question and it's answers interesting) so please don't *punish* beginners like this. The Haskell community is still one of the friendlier online places and we should try to keep it that way. Let's not get to the point where C#/Java/etc. is on this site.

Comment: Agree with @CarstenKönig. There is no need to downvote. What may be trivial to an experienced Haskeller may not be easy for the new people learning the language.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Collecting comments into an answer)

Because in haskell, a `String` **is** a list of characters, i.e. `[Char]`, just returning the input as given will do.

```
example = id
```

does what you want. Note that `id` is defined as

```
id x = x
```

Your example `"jt5x=!" -> ["j","t","5","x","=","!"]` does not match the description: Double quotes `""` enclose `String`s not single `Char`acters. For characters use single quotes `'`. You can type

```
"jt5x=!" == ['j','t','5','x','=','!']
```

into GHCi and see it returns `True`. Type `map (:[]) "jt5x=!"` to actually see `["j","t","5","x","=","!"]`.

Comment: Could i store the list     
    ["j","t","5","x","=","!"]

somewhere ? Because , i want to work with it :(

Comment: @Chryssa, better state completely what you want to do. Yes, people will spot homework questions, but try to pin down where you are stuck (and include that in your question).

Comment: @Chryssa once you see that `[Char] = String` and as soon as you understand `map` you can see that what you are looking for is `example :: String -> [String]` with `example s = map (\c -> [c]) s` - go on and try it in GHCi! (PS: I saw to late that Franky already has that in there too - I let this stand in case you don't get the `(:[])` yet ;) ) - PPS: another `example s = map return s` would work too - as soon as you understand why you will have made your first step up Mountain-M :D